# Replacing combo box editor for JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have created a customized editor for my table by extending default editor in java. The code look like

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.text.ChoiceFormat;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import com.ushustech.nmsazzist.model.mib.MibVariableModel;


public class MibFormattedValueEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
{

private JComboBox m_comboBox;
public MibFormattedValueEditor()
{
    this(new JComboBox());
}

public MibFormattedValueEditor(JComboBox comboBox)
{
    super(comboBox);
    this.m_comboBox = comboBox;
}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue()
{
    return this.m_comboBox.getSelectedItem();
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
{
    this.m_comboBox.removeAllItems();
    MibVariableModel model = (MibVariableModel) table.getModel();
    ChoiceFormat format = model.getMibVariable(row).getFormat();

    if(null != format){
        Object[] obj = format.getFormats();
        for(int i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
            this.m_comboBox.addItem(obj[i].toString());
        }

    }

    return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);

}

}
```

I want to display a text field editor if the format is null ? Please Help me for doing this? Thanks.

Comment: is there real reason to change built_in support or each of JComboBox(es) can have got different comboboxmodel :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't replace the `ComboBox` as this can get dirty. I would rather set it editable in case of `format == null` and let the user input the information here. Like this:

```
if(null != format) {
   // ...
} else {
   this.m_comboBox.setEditable(true);
}
```

Comment: How can i do that? If You don't mind would you please help me?

Comment: @Nikhil I've added an example

Answer (score -1):

Make the textField not visible by default and when the format is null set visible to true:

```
textField.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He wants to replace the ComboBox by a TestField in case of null.